# Definition of a metric space: why $E\times E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In the definition of a metric space

> Let $E$ be a set and $d:E\times E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function. $d$ is a **distance** on $E$ if ...,

why is the function $d:E\times E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a mapping from $E\times E$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (as oppose to $E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$)? Euclidean distance measured in $\mathbb{R}^2$ doesn't take a four dimensional vector and map it to a real, does it?

Comment: The Euclidean distance is given by the norm of the difference between two points, so $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. So, while the distance function takes a pair of points, it can sometimes be expressed in terms of a function that takes a single 'point'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate the distance between a **pair** of points. Pairs of points in $E$ are elements of $E \times E$. Another way of saying that is that the distance function takes **two** inputs.

Comment: thank you for your response. I guess my confusion really stems from here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch7.pdf

Please see example 7.4

Comment: This is in line with my explanation. You take the distance from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$. These two inputs have a total of $4$ pieces of information, $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$, which you can think of as an element of $\mathbb{R}^4$ if you want.

Comment: it's a little strange, as the intermediate computation is $(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2$. I don't know if I would call that an element of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: No, the input is four real numbers $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$. The output is a single real number.

Comment: thank you...that really makes sense.